# Is my proof that the square root of all imperfect squares are irrational correct?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, radicals

I was answering a Quora question about whether $\sqrt{13}$ is irrational or not [(link if needed)](https://www.quora.com/Is-the-square-root-of-13-an-irrational-rational-integer-or-a-whole-number/answer/Ben-Wornes), and I tried to prove that, in fact, the square root of all imperfect squares are irrational.

This is the first proof I have ever attempted, not knowing anything about them before-hand, and I barely know the mathematical symbols, never-mind how to properly set out a proof. So, keeping in mind that I am a complete newbie, can you tell me whether my proof is in fact correct or not, and if it isn't, where I went wrong and how I could improve it next time.

Also, if I chose the wrong symbol, please point out the where the mistake was and what the correct symbol would have been.

**Start of Proof**

Let's suppose that $n \in \mathbb{N} = \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ is not a perfect square.

This is going to be a proof by contradiction, so we are going to start out by assuming that $\sqrt{n}$ is indeed a rational number, that can be expressed in the irreducible fraction $\frac{A}{B}$ where $A, B \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ and $B \neq 1 \because \iff B = 1, \sqrt{n} = A$ which means $n = A^{2}$ which means $n$ is a perfect square.

$\sqrt{n} = \frac{A}{B}$

We can then square both sides to get:

$n = \frac{A^{2}}{B^{2}}$

Since $\frac{A}{B}$ is an irreducible fraction, $A$ and $B$ must not share any factors. When we square a number, we merely repeat its factors, therefore $A^{2}$ and $B^{2}$ must also not share any factors except $1$, making the fraction $\frac{A^{2}}{B^{2}}$ also irreducible.

Bacause it is irreducible, this means $\frac{A^{2}}{B^{2}} \notin \mathbb{Z}^{+} \because B^{2} > B \forall B > 1$ and $ B \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ and $B \neq 1$.

Since $n =  \frac{A^{2}}{B^{2}}$, this means that $n \notin \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ also.

$\because n \notin \mathbb{Z}^{+}, \sqrt{n} \notin \mathbb{Z}^{+}, \sqrt{n} \neq \frac{A}{B}$

As we had previously defined $n$ to be a positive integer, this is a contradiction. Therefore, our assumption that $\sqrt{n}$ could be expressed as the ratio of two integers was incorrect. Hence $\sqrt{n}$ is irrational $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} = \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ where $n$ is not a perfect square.

$\mathbb{Q.E.D.}$

**End of Proof**

Thanks for taking the time to read my proof. I would appreciate any and all feedback. As said, I am completely new at this so please show me where I went wrong and how to improve if I did in fact go wrong.

*~Edits~*:

- Changed the penultimate statement $\because n \notin \mathbb{Z}^{+}, \sqrt{n} \notin \mathbb{Z}^{+}, n \neq \frac{A}{B}$ by adding a radical to the last $n$ that was previously missing: $\because n \notin \mathbb{Z}^{+}, \sqrt{n} \notin \mathbb{Z}^{+}, \sqrt{n} \neq \frac{A}{B}$
- Added a concise contradiction as opposed to ending the proof by simply stating that $\because n \notin \mathbb{Z}^{+}, \sqrt{n} \notin \mathbb{Z}^{+}, \sqrt{n} \neq \frac{A}{B}$ without looping back to the opening when we defined $n$ as an integer.
- Further reinstated why $\frac{A}{B} \notin \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ by adding reasoning that $\because B^{2} > B \forall B > 1$ and $ B \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ and $B \neq 1$, along with the fact that $\frac{A^{2}}{B^{2}}$ is irreducible.

Credit to [Mathew Daly](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/694818/matthew-daly) for helping me improve the summary.

Comment: This is the first time I've ever heard of a number that is not a perfect square refered to as an "imperfect square".

Comment: I *think* there is circular logic in here, but if there is (and that is a big if) it will be tough to find. In any case, this is a lovely first post, correct or not. Welcome.

Comment: It's not really circular so much as assuming much has been proven to make the proof unnecessary.  We are assuming integers have unique factorizations and all rationals have a unique expression in lowest terms.  Those are not trivial things to prove.  But once they are proven this follows immediately.  I think the OP argued well.

Comment: The 'repeat its factors' part, while correct, is where I think the circular logic happens. But I also found this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2912592/let-n-in-mathbbn-such-that-n-is-a-non-perfect-square-show-that-sqrtn?rq=1

Comment: Indeed, after checking out the link I posted, I believe we have a correct, if unorthodox, proof. It might get some pushback from people who are used to such facts being proved in a certain way, but if you are totally new to this than this is *extremely* impressive, at least to me.

Comment: It boils down to "When we square a number, we merely repeat its factors, therefore $A^2$ and $B^2$ must also not share any factors except 1".  I think that needs to be more formally expressed.  But it is correct.  I had forgotten I had put an answer on the page.  My answer was essentially the OP's proof but I specifically spelled out that any prime factor of $A$ must be a prime factor of $B$.  But that's essentially the OP's argument.

Comment: Agreed entirely.

Comment: I would also add that $B^2 > 1$ to reinforce the notion we are using the fact that a fraction in lowest terms with a denominator > 1 is not an integer.  It’s a minor point because the inequality is obvious, but at this stage of proof writing it’s important to be clear about *how* you know what may seem obvious.

Comment: I added the "elementary-number-theory" tag to your post.  Cheers!

Comment: Claiming that "$A$ and $B$ share no factors implies that $A^2$ and $B^2$ share no factors" assumes what is to be shown. To see this, assume the negation of what we are trying to prove, that there is a rational $A/B$, with $(A,B)=1$, that is not an integer but that $(A/B)^2=N$ is an integer. That is, $A^2=B^2N$, so that $(A^2,B^2)=B^2$ and since $A/B$ is not an integer, $B\gt1$ and thus, $B^2\gt1$. That is, $A^2$ and $B^2$ share a factor greater than $1$.

Comment: Yves Daoust states the argument (indeed, a more general argument) very succinctly [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1345466/213690).

Comment: @Calum Yves anwer is not rigorous since it gives no justification for the claim that $p/q$ irreducible implies $\,p^b/q^b\,$ irreducible (which is the heart of the matter). See my answer for more on that.

Comment: @BillDubuque What about my two comments [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2977930/213690)?

Comment: @Calum Your linked proof is rigorous and complete since you explicitly state (and even prove) the ancillary theorem(s) that you employ. Btw, the general Euclid's lemma that you use $\,(c,b)=1,\ c\mid ab\,\Rightarrow\, c\mid a\,$ is trivially equivalent to uniqueness of prime factorizations (and also to unique fractionization, i.e. the denominator of a reduced fraction divides every possible denominator), e.g. [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/825871/242). Btw,  every integer $> 1$ has a prime factor is part of the proof of *existence* (not uniqueness) of prime factorizations.

Comment: @BillDubuque If I understand you correctly, Daoust's proof could be made rigorous by the insertion of a brief clause in justification, causing it to read something like this, in toto: "If $p/q$ is an irreducible fraction, so is $(p/q)^b=(p^b)/(q^b)$, because $p$ and $q$ have no common prime factor, and prime factorisations are unique. So a power of a fraction cannot give an integer." I'd still call that concise, so I'd be fairly happy with it, too. My only slight unhappiness comes from the feeling, even if it's unjustifiable, that unique factorisation is an unnecessarily complex result to use.

Comment: @Calum The problem with Daoust's argument (and same in the OP above) is discussed at length in the "terrifying" thread linked in my answer. The "proof" gives only the first (trivial) step. It is impossible to determine what the author believes about the nontrivial steps that remain (or even if the author realizes that it is incomplete). It is quite common that students don't think more need be said (wrongly believing it is true in all rings) or don't know how to finish, or give erroneous completions, etc.

Comment: @Calum You need to say more than "prime factorizations are unique"  (FTA) to give a complete rigorous proof that $\,\gcd(p,q)=1\,\Rightarrow\, \gcd(p^n,q^n) = 1.\,$  Almost all (divisibility) theorems of elementary number theory are consequences of FTA but that doesn't mean that we can omit all of their proofs (if so ENT textbooks would be empty!)

Comment: @BillDubuque I have now read the nine-year-old thread to which you referred. Objectively, I can add nothing to it. Subjectively, I hope that today's "extended discussion in comments" ends here! The word "terrified" is not too strong to express how I feel, having read comments by Aryabhata that express my own thoughts exactly! I appreciate some of the points that you, in particular, made in response, but I agree with Qiaochu Yuan that "Whatever we are arguing about, it is not mathematics." I had no idea I was helping to open such a can of worms! Is there an ancient Egyptian curse on this topic?

Comment: @Callum Yes, alas, we're cursed with extremely strong *intuition* on  integer arithmetic - hardwired into our minds long before we learn to reason deductively (vs. empirically). In order to compensate, number theory teachers have no choice but to insist that students make it very clear that they are reasoning deductively. Even Gauss lamented about such when he gave the first complete rigorous proof of FTA: "However we did not wish to omit [the proof of Euclid's Lemma] because many modern authors have offered up feeble arguments in place of proof or have neglected the theorem completely."

Comment: Again, $150$ years later, another eminent number theorist Harold Davenport wrote about FTA in his famous textbook *The Higher Arithmetic* "it is passed over without explanation in many schoolbooks. One of them (still in use) describes it as a ‘law of thought’, which it certainly is not." And, as we can see from discussions here, analogous (pedagogical and epistemological) problems persist to this day.

Answer (score 4):

I will mention one (easily corrected) logical error and one stylistic piece of advice that could make the proof more readable.  But the upshot is that this is a well-argued proof by any standard, and especially impressive for a first effort.

When you said that $A^2$ and $B^2$ share no factors aside from 1, that does not imply that $\frac{A^2}{B^2}$ is not an integer.  You merely showed that it is a simplified rational number.  That is an important step, but ultimately, you need to add that $B^2\neq 1$.  As I said earlier, this is nearly trivial to address, since $B^2>B$ for all $B>1$.  But it is worth addressing key points in proofs even if they are trivial.

Stylistically, I felt a bit let down when you hit the contradiction.  It's kind of a climax of the proof, so you should feel free to emphasize it.  More importantly, you want to specifically point out the contradiction and the original assumption that you now know to be false (as this is a proof that's long enough that we've likely forgotten the beginning by now).  If I had written this, I might have ended it like this:

> As we had previously defined $n$ to be a positive integer, this is a contradiction.  Therefore, our assumption that $\sqrt n$ could be expressed as the ratio of two integers was incorrect.  Hence $\sqrt n$  is irrational.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I am pleased to hear that I did well for my first proof, I felt like I must have made a few large mistakes before I published it to here. I will definitely take note of the stylistic changes you have mentioned for any further proofs I do. Also, I get what you are saying about implicitly stating that $B^{2} > 1$, but is this needed been as I previously stated that $B \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ and $B \neq 1$? Wouldn't one naturally relate that $B^{2} > B \forall B > 1$ which means $B^{2} > 1$?

Comment: It's a balancing act.  You don't want to bore your audience, but you also don't want to suggest that you didn't consider important things.  In this case, showing that a fraction isn't an integer has two steps -- showing that they don't have any non-trivial factors and showing that the denominator isn't zero.  You put the right amount of effort in the first step in your proof, and you put the right amount of effort into the second step in what you just wrote in your comment.

Comment: I see, thanks for taking the time to read and reply to my post!

Comment: I hope that the edits I just made helped make the proof better, I took much thought from your answer, thanks.

Comment: @Matthew The inference $B>1\,\Rightarrow\, B^2>1\,$ is much more trivial than $\,\gcd(A,B)=1\,\Rightarrow\, \gcd(A^2,B^2)=1.\,$ Justification of the  former might be omitted, but the latter should never be omitted (at this level) since it employs deep properties of the integers (e.g. Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic) that are often wrongly assumed to hold more generally than they do  (or wrongly assumed not to need any justification) - see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You may have the right idea, but for the proof to be complete and rigorous you need to more clearly justify the following crucial inference:

> When we square a number, we merely repeat its factors, therefore $A^2$ and $B^2$ must also not share any factors".

As it stands, your justification "when we square a number, we merely repeat its factors" could be interpreted in a way that it is true in any number system (ring). But the result is not true that generally. Likely you have in mind an argument that uses more *specific* divisibility properties that hold true for integers,  e.g. the fundamental theorem of arithmetic (existence and uniqueness of *prime* factorizations) or closely related properties such as Euclid's Lemma, gcd laws, etc. It is *essential* to explicitly mention such properties in order to obtain a well-founded argument.

But so little is said (e.g. not even any mention of primes) that there is no way for the reader to accurately judge the intent and correctness of the argument. It is quite common for beginners to wrongly believe that such properties are trivially true for all number systems, or to believe that a proof is (intuitively) "obvious" but then not know how to rigorously prove it when the gap is revealed.

Let's consider a simple counterexample - the [Hilbert naturals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_number) $\,\Bbb H = 1+4\,\Bbb N = 1,5,9,13,\ldots$ Here $\,3\not\in\Bbb H\,\Rightarrow\,\gcd(9,21)=1\,$ but $\,\gcd(9^2,21^2) = 9\gcd(9,49)=9\,$ by $\,9,49\in\Bbb H.\,$
 So your quoted claim fails here. You may find it instructive to study why it fails. Also unique prime factorization fails, e.g. two distinct $\Bbb H\text{--prime}$ factorizatioms$\ 9\cdot 49 = 21^2$ [arising from $\,3^2 7^2 = (3\cdot 7)^2$ in $\Bbb N$].

The level of detail that should be required in arguments like this is subjective and context dependent. In a first course in proofs an instructor may be most concerned with teaching general proof strategies so may gloss over tangents on number-theoretical intricacies. But in a course in number theory or algebra these intricacies are the heart of the matter. If one doesn't master them then one will soon be led astray in more general number systems (e.g. quadratic algebraic  numbers) where some of the familiar properties of integers (like those above) no longer hold true. There *empirical*  inference based upon integer arithmetical intuition may fail miserably. Instead we must rely on *deductive* inference based on fundamental divisibility properties and their logical relationships. One of the main goals of a course in elementary number theory is to abstract out these essential arithmetical properties so they can be applied correctly in more general number systems (e.g. the basic results thats for integral domains [we have](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/164589/242) Euclidean $\Rightarrow$ PID $\Rightarrow$ UFD $\Rightarrow$ GCD $\Rightarrow$ Schreier, and no arrow reverses).

At first glance this may seem overkill for integers. But the need for such rigor and abstraction becomes clear when we leave the familiar domain of integers and enter arithmetical domains where intuition fails miserably. Indeed, lacking such rigorous foundations even eminent mathematicians made major mistakes in the past (e.g. some attempted proofs of FLT wrongly assumed without proof that some rings of algebraic integers had divisibility properties similar to integers).

These matters have been discussed here in the past, with varying degrees of success. You may find it of interest to read some prior discussions on such matters, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4572/242) (beware that one mathematician deemed the thread to be [terrifying](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4572/is-this-proof-of-a1-2-being-either-integer-or-irrational-circular-incorrect#comment9889_4572)!) But it does cover the essential points, and illustrates the innate difficulties involved in such subjective pedagogical discussions with a very diverse audience.