# Seeking reference for "prome" example (showing unique factorization isn't obvious)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request

The Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic says that every positive integer can be expressed **uniquely** as a product of primes. Although this theorem is famous and has been known for a long time, it is not trivial, and is not as simple to prove as the fact that every positive integer can be written in **at least one way** as a product of primes.

There's a cute example that I think does a good job of explaining to students (and to experienced mathematicians, for that matter) why the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic isn't obvious. I saw it somewhere when I was an undergraduate, but I can't remember where.

That example is: Suppose our number system consists of all **even** positive integers, and we call such a number "prome" if it cannot be written as a product of two smaller numbers in the set. Then:

2 is prome

4 is not prome (4 = 2*2)

6 is prome (because 1*6 and 2*3 are not factorizations into even integers)

8 is not prome (8 = 2*4)

10 is prome (because 1*10 and 2*5 are not factorizations into even integers)

12 is not prome (12 = 2*6)

We can then notice that 36 can be written as a product of "promes" in two different ways: 2*18 and 6*6.

My question is: **Where did I see this argument?** I believe I may have read it in a textbook in the library of my undergraduate institution, which would make it no later than 1995. (The word "prome" was used in the document I read; it's not my paraphrase.)

Comment: I found, with Google, [Elementary Number Theory by Underwood Dudley](https://archive.org/details/ElementaryNumberTheory) uses the word "prome" to describe a similar example of multiplicatively irreducible elements in the set $4\mathbb N + 1$ - maybe that's what you're thinking of?

Comment: Joseph H Silverman, in Chapter 7 of A Friendly Introduction to Number Theory, makes a similar presentation, calling the system of even numbers "the $\mathbb E$-zone."

Comment: Interesting, and thanks to you both! It's possible that I conflated Dudley's discussion (using the word "prome") with the even number example described by Silverman (and/or possibly others).

Comment: See also the [Hilbert naturals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_number) $\,1+4\Bbb N,\,$ e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3330090/242) and [here](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/6107/163), both of which include further related discussion on this topic.

Comment: What does prome mean? I couldn't find it related to math in a google search.

Comment: @poetasis From the post: "Suppose our number system consists of all even positive integers, and we call such a number 'prome' if it cannot be written as a product of two smaller numbers in the set. "

Comment: @poetasis 'prome' is not a standard math term.  It's a definition just given (by Dudley, apparently) for pedagogical reasons.